# Python - Conditionals in tuple of tuples without looping

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements

I'm new to Python (coming from C and going thru LinkedIn Learning) and am trying to learn more about efficient coding practices and Python.  I have a program that will be used in a bigger project but trying to see if there is a more efficient way rather than looping.  I have a temp, that will be compared to a tuple of tuples.  Each tuple has the upper and lower range and an associated word that will be the output.  I can loop thru just fine, but is there a more effective way?  Here is the looping way I got working.  Thanks.

```
# Set constants and list values
record_cold = -89
record_hot = 56.7
err_string = 'ERROR : Not in range \n        Or you just broke a record temp'

temp_list = (
    (record_cold, -10, 'stone cold'),
    (-10, 0, 'cold'),
    (0, 10, 'chilly'),
    (10, 20, 'nice'),
    (20, 30, 'bar-b-que time'),
    (30, 40, 'tanning'),
    (40, 50, 'hot'),
    (50, record_hot, 'too damn hot')
    )

curr_temp = 25

for i in temp_list:
    if curr_temp >= i[0]:
        if curr_temp < i[1]:
            output = i[2]
            break
    if True:
        output = err_string

print(f'{output}')
```

Comment: If you're looking for improvements to working code, that would be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but after seeing things like `if True:` and `print(f'{output}')` in your code I can tell you that you might want to first spend more time proofreading on your own. And also look into a traditional `if..elif..else` structure rather than looping through a tuple. These aren't Python-specific things, either; they would also apply to C.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about Code Review.  I used the `If True:` statement cause if the temp didn't meet any of the conditions, it's out of range.  As for the `print(f...)` that is what my online lessons taught for simple print statements.  I thought `if, elif, else` would be too long and repetitive especially if the list grows to be more granular.

Comment: Your justification of `if True:` is incorrect, because that statement is never justified. An `if..elif..else` structure is comparable to `if..else if..else` or a switch/case in C. Are you familiar with those? It sounds like you need to review those lessons more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If the temp is constant, you could do :

```
if (curr_temp >= 50): output = 'too damn hot'
elif (curr_temp >= 40): output = 'hot'
elif (curr_temp >= 30): output = 'tanning'
# and so on
```

in which case a loop is not necessary

Otherwise, if the size of the list is subject to change, it's difficult to avoid a loop. But you can make it more concise :

```
for i in temp_list:
   if curr_temp < i[1]:
       output = i[2]
       break
```

(assuming that current_temp is never outside the min and max values otherwise you should handle that before the loop)

Comment: Sorry forgot, for context this function will be in a while loop constantly updating with new current temp values.

Comment: @marcellatwin - That doesn't preclude the use of such a structure.